# Redirection from a Secure Page

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, ssl

I have 2 domain one is **https://app.example.com** which on which SSL is configured and the other one is **http://www.example.com** (SSL was for this site configured earlier when http://app.example.com was without SSL) on which no SSL is configured.

Problem is that when my user mistakenly enter https://www.example.com which is not a SSL enabled site. The users are shown the contents of my SSL enabled site.

Both https://app.example.com and http://www.example.com are on same server with same IP Address.

How can i restrict that users should be shown the contents of the site which user entered. (im aware that when user will hit my non SSL enabled site they will be shown SSL cert warning, but this not the issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mod_rewrite` module should be helpful in this case. You can try to put these rules to your SSL virtual host definition:

```
RewriteEngine On                                       # enable mod rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on                                # if  is was used
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]       # and if the host is www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L] # then rewrite the url it to http
```